# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

Hey guys I'm working on a Java application with springboot, I'm a beginner with springboot and every time I try to run the project I get these errors, I don't know what's going on, I've already reviewed many articles and none can help me with this going.
I leave you the code of the application.properties and the errors that it throws when running the application
Thank you

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/springboot?useSSL=false&useTimeZone=true&serverTimeZone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Images of errors

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG7BW.png)

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzi4E.png)

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QphDK.png)

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zPtJ.png)

I hope you can help me

if you need to see more code tell me

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that the message "Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost'" is not correct?

Comment: First thing to do is to ensure that the db is listening on that port bound to that address (netstat). Second thing to do is to make sure you can connect *from the same host* as you're running that datasource on with the same credentials. Use the mysql client

Answer (score 0):

```
grant all privileges on springboot.* to root@'%' identified by 'admin';
flush privileges;
```

Try run it in your MySQL.